# Sql Server count number of days customer was enrolled in discount program

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a problem where I need to count how many months a customer participated in a program.  The count is to see whether the customer took action on the 15th of the month.  There are a number of rows of data like the following:

```
CustoemerId ProgramStartDate    ProgramEndDate
009         2014-03-01          2014-03-31
009         2014-04-01          2014-05-31
321         2014-01-11          2014-01-31
523         2014-03-11          2014-03-31
314         2014-04-01          2014-05-31
314         2014-06-01          2014-06-30
949         2014-05-02          2014-05-31
668         2014-02-01          2014-03-31
433         2014-01-01          2014-01-14
885         2014-04-16          2014-05-14
```

I need a Sql Server Query (v. 2014 if that helps) that tells me that customer 009 has 3 months enrollment (15th of Feb, 15th of April, 15th of May), as does 314.  The rest have one month except 433 and 885 who have 0, since they were not in the program on the 15th of the partial month in which they were enrolled.

Output would look like:
    CustomerId  MonthsEnrolled
    009            3
    321            1
    523            1
    314            3
    949            1
    668            1

I don't need the zero counts, but if the sample solution includes them, I think I can get to where I need.

My approach, which fails badly in the two multiple cases, was to simply grab all rows where the 15th appears between begin and end date and count by customer number. That miscounted both of those members.

Comment: so you are looking for a query which gives  " if users are enrolled on  15th of said months " plus users  who are not enrolled ?

Comment: `I need ..... ` but you dont explain the logic to get that. Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

Comment: 668 also has 2 months

Comment: @TheGameiswar I edited the question to show what the output should look like.  Beyond that, I'm not sure I understand how to make the problem clearer.

Comment: @FLICKER Yep, if I could award double-secret bonus points, you'd get them.  A, your solution is breathtakingly simple and PTF inducing.  B found a 3rd row where my initial count was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sample Data

```
create table #tt (CustomerId int, StartDate date, EndDate date)
insert into #tt values 
(009,         '2014-03-01',          '2014-03-31'),
(009,         '2014-04-01',          '2014-05-31'),
(321,         '2014-01-11',          '2014-01-31'),
(523,         '2014-03-11',          '2014-03-31'),
(314,         '2014-04-01',          '2014-05-31'),
(314,         '2014-06-01',          '2014-06-30'),
(949,         '2014-05-02',          '2014-05-31'),
(668,         '2014-02-01',          '2014-03-31'),
(433,         '2014-01-01',          '2014-01-14'),
(885,         '2014-04-16',          '2014-05-14')
```

You need to create a temp table containing 15th of all months. This is not a big deal

```
create table #fiftheens (dr date)
insert into #fiftheens values 
      ('2014-01-15'), ('2014-02-15'), ('2014-03-15')
    , ('2014-04-15'), ('2014-05-15'), ('2014-06-15')
    , ('2014-07-15'), ('2014-08-15'), ('2014-09-15')
    , ('2014-10-15'), ('2014-11-15'),  ('2014-12-15')
```

Following query returns the result you want

```
select *
from #tt
  left join #fiftheens on #fiftheens.dr between #tt.StartDate and #tt.EndDate


+------------+------------+------------+------------+
| CustomerId | StartDate  |  EndDate   |     dr     |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
|          9 | 2014-03-01 | 2014-03-31 | 2014-03-15 |
|          9 | 2014-04-01 | 2014-05-31 | 2014-04-15 |
|          9 | 2014-04-01 | 2014-05-31 | 2014-05-15 |
|        321 | 2014-01-11 | 2014-01-31 | 2014-01-15 |
|        523 | 2014-03-11 | 2014-03-31 | 2014-03-15 |
|        314 | 2014-04-01 | 2014-05-31 | 2014-04-15 |
|        314 | 2014-04-01 | 2014-05-31 | 2014-05-15 |
|        314 | 2014-06-01 | 2014-06-30 | 2014-06-15 |
|        949 | 2014-05-02 | 2014-05-31 | 2014-05-15 |
|        668 | 2014-02-01 | 2014-03-31 | 2014-02-15 |
|        668 | 2014-02-01 | 2014-03-31 | 2014-03-15 |
|        433 | 2014-01-01 | 2014-01-14 | NULL       |
|        885 | 2014-04-16 | 2014-05-14 | NULL       |
+------------+------------+------------+------------+
```

You can find out using the result records, by counting.

Answer (score 0):

Start with a CTE or table that contains a datetime column with the 15th of all the months you would be interested in checking.

Then JOIN your data table to that date table on the 15th being between your start and end dates, and you will generate one row for every month you are looking for.

Then just count the rows, obviously.